# Precalculus linear combination problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, linear-transformations

What is the maximum possible length of the vector resulting from the following linear combination?
$$
\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_1} \|} \,\mathbf{v_1} + \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{v_2}\|} \,\mathbf{v_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_n} \|} \,\mathbf{v_n}
$$

Comment: Suppose  $v_1 = v_2 = \cdots = v_n$

Comment: @DougM If that was the case, then the expression would simplify to $\frac{n \cdot \mathbf{v_1}}{|\mathbf{v_1}|}$.

Comment: And what is the magnitude of that vector?

Comment: @DougM It would be $n$, correct? And if this is the case, wouldn't the answer be infinitely large?

Comment: Yes, it would be $n.$ But $n$ is not infinite, $n$ is $n.$  Something I should have said at the beginning.  The triangle inequality says $\|v_1\| +\|v_2\| \ge \|v_1 + v_2\|$ the precludes your sum from being larger than $n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{u_i} = \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_i} \|} \,\mathbf{v_i}$, then $\| \mathbf{u_i} \| = 1.$

$
\Big\|\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_1} \|} \,\mathbf{v_1} + \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{v_2}\|} \,\mathbf{v_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_n} \|} \,\mathbf{v_n}\Big\| = 
\| \mathbf{u_1} +  \mathbf{u_2} + \dots + \mathbf{u_n}\| \le \| \mathbf{u_1}\| +  \|\mathbf{u_2}\| + \dots + \|\mathbf{u_n}\| = n.$